# How to retrieve flashvars of a GET request content?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, httprequest, rails-admin

I want to add custom button to rails_admin new/edit page of specific model.

This button should parse the content of a get request to a custom URL.

The current problem I found using JQuery approach like this:

```
$('#your_button_id').click(function () {
  $.get('your_url', function(data) {
    //$('.result').html(data); - sample
    //Do whatever you want
    alert('Load was performed.');
  });
});
```

Is that it don't load the flashvars attribute.

I was wondering if there is any other alternative to retrieve the whole content with the flashvars included.

Comment: under scrape you mean parse data from some url?

Comment: Yes, exactry. I want to get some data from the URL. i just want to put only URL to the form.

Comment: there is method called .parse, google it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to get just the URL or the response to a get request, so:

If you want the URL:

```
$('#your_button_id').click(function () {
  var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
  //manipulate the url in sPageURL
});
```

If you want the content of the url:

```
$('#your_button_id').click(function () {
  $.get('your_url', function(data) {
    //$('.result').html(data); - sample
    //Do whatever you want
    alert('Load was performed.');
  });
});
```

References:

- [JQuery Load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)
- [JQuery Get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Comment: I edites your question, it seems more accurate to your needs!

Comment: I have already tried this method, but i couldn't get flashvars attr of embed element. thanx anyway.